# Hierarchical force diagram using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hierarchy, force-layout

I would like to generate a hierarchical force diagram using D3.js - a force directed graph that allows you to navigate a tree-like structure by clicking on nodes expanding the graph to the children level (where the relationships between the childrens are shown). The nodes can be related to each other in two ways, parent or sibling. The parent relationship indicates that nodes "belong to" their parent.

As a starting point I have looked at the force cluster example: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/force/force-cluster.html, and included the relationships above but I can't figure out how to only render the expanded cluster and not the whole network (see image below).

```
JSON data:
{"nodes":
        [
        {"name":"Person 0","group":"Person 0"},
        {"name":"Person 1","group":"Person 1"},
        {"name":"Person 2","group":"Person 1"},
        {"name":"Person 3","group":"Person 1"},     
        {"name":"Person 4","group":"Person 3"},
        {"name":"Person 5","group":"Person 3"}  
        ],
"links":
        [
        {"source":1,"target":0,"type":"sibling"},
        {"source":2,"target":1,"type":"parent"},
        {"source":3,"target":1,"type":"parent"},
        {"source":3,"target":2,"type":"sibling"},
        {"source":4,"target":3,"type":"parent"},
        {"source":5,"target":3,"type":"parent"},
        {"source":4,"target":5,"type":"sibling"}
        ]
}
```

[image: Expanding cluster]

Above: Force diagram, where the red links indicate the sibling relationship.

It would also be possible to arrange the "children" as children in the JSON, instead of using the parent "type":

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "name": "Person 0",
    },
    {
        "name": "Person 1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Person 2",
            },
            {
.
.
.
"links": [
    {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 0
    },
.
.
```

However, how do you then combine the tree-structure while keeping track of the relationships  between the children nodes?

An imaginative tree-like structure would look like:
[image: Tree]

The lower section indicates a desired layout of the visual (similar function to the one in the upper image).

Do you have any suggestions of how to proceed?

Comment: I had a similar sort of problem. I wanted to show the local network around a node that was clicked from a large dataset. My solution might provide you with some pointers: timebandit.github.io/graphSub

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly, all nodes with the same direct parent are siblings. Therefore you should have no need to additionally track if nodes are siblings to each other or not.

If you happen to have nodes that are only related to other sibling nodes but have no parent (such as the relation between Person 0 and Person 1 in your example), the tree layout is not the right choice. Instead, you might want to try the force layout.